# perl regex invalid range

Tags: regex, perl

I have following regexp to check XML element names.

```
my $NameStartChar = ':A-Z_a-z\x{C0}-\x{D6}\x{D8}-\x{F6}\x{F8}-\x{2FF}\x{0370}-\x{037D}\x{37F}-\x{1FFF}\x{200C}-\x{200D}\x{2070}-\x{218F}\x{2C00}-\x{2FEF}\x{3001}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{EFFFF}';
my $NameChar = ':A-Z_a-z\x{C0}-\x{D6}\x{D8}-\x{F6}\x{F8}-\x{2FF}\x{370}-\x{37D}\x{37F}-\x{1FFF}\x{200C}-\x{200D}\x{2070}-\x{218F}\x{2C00}-\x{2FEF}\x{3001}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{EFFFF}\-\.0-9\x{B7}\x{0300}-\x{036F}\x{203F}-\x{2040}';

sub checkXmlName ($)
# Check if input is valid XML name
# $arg - Input string
# $ret - Boolean of validity
{
    if ($_[0] =~ m/^[$NameStartChar]([$NameChar])*$/)
    {    return 1;    }
    else
    {    return "";    }
}

if (checkXmlName("foo"))
{
    print STDOUT "OK";
}
```

Which gives convenient error

```
Invalid [] range "\x{F8}-\x{2FF}" in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^[:A-Z_a-z\x{C0}-\x{D6}\x{D8}-\x{F6}\x{F8}-\x{2FF} <-- HERE
```

On Perl 5.16.2 I am using `\N{U+2FF}` form of characters. But I'm mandatory to use 5.8.8.

EDIT:
Changed qw to qr which doesn't changed error.
and added `Unicode character 0xeffff is illegal at ...`

EDIT: from ikegami comment
Removed qr/ Which eliminated ilegal character error.

Comment: Aside: Why are you using `qw/.../`? That is a construction for creating lists.

Comment: So you're saying you're getting an error with 5.8.8 and not with 5.16.2, and you want ...what exactly?

Comment: `\x{F8}-\x{FF}\x{100}-\x{2FF}`?

Comment: I have to check international XML names against standard (TRUE/FALSE).

Comment: I meant, what do you want from us (given that you claim this is a bug in Perl that's already been fixed)?

Comment: I'm curently learning Perl so I needed to know where is my bug. I rewrote buggy code to `\x{F8}-\x{FF}\{100}-\{2FF}`.

Comment: It's not your bug; it's a bug in Perl. Did breaking up the range at FF help? (Include `@ikegami` in your comment so I get notified.)

Comment: @ikegami After I rewroted it to two ranges it does not throws any error and pass all given tests.

Comment: Awesome. Made an answer of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[\x{F8}-\x{2FF}]` should work, so this is a bug in Perl.

`[\x{F8}-\x{2FF}]` does work in newer versions of Perl, so this bug has been fixed.

Looks like the regex engine has problems with ranges that span from single-byte chars to larger chars, so why don't you try splitting the range into two.

```
[\x{F8}-\x{FF}\x{100}-\x{2FF}]
```